# Настройка файла .htaccess на Joomla сайте

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

Добрый день! Сайт работает под управлением CMS Joomla 2.5.6 + компонент Artio JoomSef 4.2.8. С помощью JoomSef на сайте настроены ЧПУ (человеко понятные URLы), происходит такая ситуация при обращении к странице сайта www.домен.ru/igrushki/ - открывается нужная страница а если после / добавить index.php (т.е. www.домен.ru/igrushki/index.php) - выдаёт ошибку "404 Страница не найдена". Создавать в Artio JoomSef ряд ссылок с /index.php ведущих не те же страницы что и без index.php как-то не хочтеся (много очень). Скажите может быть данная проблема как-то реализуется с помощью файла .htaccess ? Содержимое моего .htaccess.

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2012 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приведите содержание вашего .htaccess

Comment: @maler1988, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такую строку добавить сразу после строки с `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Это будет перенаправлять со всех адресов, заканчивающихся на `index.php`, на "корень" соответствующей директории: `site.ru/aaa/bbb/index.php -> site.ru/aaa/bbb/`

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает! ))

Comment: Да класс, я просто никак не изучу нормально .htaccess, для меня пока в "сайтостроении" остаются труднопонимаемыми регулярные выражения и декларации в файле .htaccess. Сталкиваюсь редко, а сесть и изучить специально (там курс пройти какой-нибудь, книжку почитать) времени нет. ) Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: а нельзя этот код чуть улучшить, а то в админку не пускает =))) там же адрес начинается с index.php XDDDD

Comment: Перед RewriteRule'ом добавьте:

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator

Comment: В общем финт граблями! вот это правило RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L] оставляем в основном файле .htaccess который лежит в корне сайта, копируем его в папку administrator и меняем в скопированном файле это правило на такое: RewriteRule ^administrator/index\.php$ /$1/index\.php [R=301,L] получается на сайте все /index.php редиректит на / , а вдминке всё продолжает работать. Спсибо! =)